# I'm having a problem with gnu gcc ld syntax

Tags: gcc, syntax, ld

Okay, I'm rather new to gcc and ld and I'm clearly missing something, but I can't seem to find a specific answer here, in "Using ld", or elsewhere on the net.

I'm using a simple source code file I pulled off the net (I've saved it as dummy.c):

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main () {
    int ch;

    for( ch = 75 ; ch <= 100; ch++ ) {
       printf("ASCII value = %d, Character = %c\n", ch , ch );
    }

    return(0);
 }
```

---

```
 gcc dummy.c
```

works, and then

```
 ./a.out
```

also works.

And, the more specific:

```
 gcc -o dummy dummy.c
```

works, and then

```
 ./dummy
```

also works.

But then I delete a.out and dummy and try:

```
 gcc -c dummy.c
```

which produces dummy.o

And then I do:

```
 ld -o dummy dummy.o -lc
```

But this results in:

```
 ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008049020
```

and, although it produces dummy, trying ./dummy results in:

```
 -bash: ./dummy: No such file or directory
```

even though dummy is clearly in the directory (with permissions 755).

What am I doing wrong?

=====

As recommended by ssbssa below, I tried gcc -v dummy.c --> The result was:

```
 Using built-in specs.
 COLLECT_GCC=gcc
 COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper
 Target: i686-linux-gnu
 Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 8.3.0-6' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=i686-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-targets=all --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
 Thread model: posix
 gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
 COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
  /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch i386-linux-gnu dummy.c -quiet -dumpbase dummy.c -mtune=generic -march=i686 -auxbase dummy -version -o /tmp/ccbFKhxi.s
 GNU C17 (Debian 8.3.0-6) version 8.3.0 (i686-linux-gnu)
         compiled by GNU C version 8.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.20-GMP

 GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
 ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/i386-linux-gnu"
 ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/include"
 #include "..." search starts here:
 #include <...> search starts here:
  /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/include
  /usr/local/include
  /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/include-fixed
  /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
  /usr/include
 End of search list.
 GNU C17 (Debian 8.3.0-6) version 8.3.0 (i686-linux-gnu)
         compiled by GNU C version 8.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.20-GMP

 GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
 Compiler executable checksum: c52019c44a1e362eeb6021f108314d7e
 COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
  as -v --32 -o /tmp/ccORYUuk.o /tmp/ccbFKhxi.s
 GNU assembler version 2.31.1 (i686-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.31.1
 COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/
 LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib/:/lib/i386-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
 COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
  /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cci9u5um.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -pie /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/../../../i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib -L/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/../../.. /tmp/ccORYUuk.o -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o
 COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
```

The only thing that even looks a little bit like "ld" seems to be in the next -to-the-last line, a little less than halfway across the scrolling screen at:

```
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -pie
```

Thanks ssbssa; I'll play around with that a bit and see what happens. I'll also go through the specific documentation page you pointed to.

---

After looking into ssbssa's recommended references and a few others, I began to suspect that ld really shouldn't be as complicated as those references make it seem. So, I tried a simple straight assembly source program:

```
 # From GASProfessional Book - location 108 ff
 # cpuid.s Sample program to extract the processor Vendor ID

 .section .data

 output:
   .ascii "The processor Vendor ID is 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'\n"

 .section .text

 .globl _start

 _start:

   movl $0, %eax           # Get the CPU's Vendor ID
   cpuid

   movl $output, %edi      # Setup the output string
   movl %ebx, 28(%edi)
   movl %edx, 32(%edi)
   movl %ecx, 36(%edi)

   movl $4, %eax           # Display the output string
   movl $1, %ebx
   movl $output, %ecx
   movl $42, %edx
   int $0x80

   movl $1, %eax           # Exit 0
   movl $0, %ebx
   int $0x80
```

Then I did:

```
 as -o cpuid.o cpuid.s
```

and:

```
 ld -o cpuid cpuid.s
```

and the command:

```
 ./cpuid
```

then produced:

```
 The processor Vendor ID is 'GenuineIntel'
```

as expected.

So, in the c program, perhaps I need to play around with main vs. _start ?? Onward, into the breach !!

Comment: Try `gcc -v dummy.c` to see how gcc invokes ld, it's not that easy as you think (also, see [ld documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html)).

Comment: Well, you certainly seem to be right about it not being easy. Please see above.

Comment: You edit looks incomplete.

Comment: Yes, it took awhile to get it all in and add the spaces at the left to make it appear as code.

Comment: AFAIK, the `collect2` process of the penultimate line calls then `ld` with more or less the same arguments.

Comment: But is there actually a reason why you need to call `ld` directly instead of letting `gcc` do the hard work for you? Or are you just curious how this works behind the scenes?

Comment: Once I figure this all out, I want to access the cpuid opcode and the nanotimer. I understand these are both significantly easier to accomplish in the assembler than in c. Thus, I will be linking object files, some of which were compiled by c, and others which were assembled by as. I suspect that ld is the way to do that, although I've seen a couple of blurbs in my reading which seem to indicate I can do even that with gcc proper. Still learning.

Comment: I don't know about nanotimer, but there is a [cpuid header interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17769071/1983398), or you could use [inline assembly](https://wiki.osdev.org/CPUID#Using_CPUID_from_GCC).

Comment: I want to avoid inline assembly. After I get something built and running on x86-64, I'll probably want to port it to ARM and perhaps a few other things. Keeping the assembly completely separate from c should greatly facilitate that. I'll go take a look at the cpuid header interface though. Thanks.

Comment: I tried a straight assembly program for reference - see above.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you want to use ld directly tho, you can add the object files by assembler to your gcc link command as well.

Comment: Thanks ssbssa, I'll experiment a bit with that too.

Answer (score 1):

> ld -o dummy dummy.o -lc

In general, you don't want to call `ld` directly.  Instead, use `gcc` to link. `gcc` is actually just a driver program that calls the needed sup-processes (compiler proper (`cc1` for C, `cc1plus` for C++), assembler `as`, linker `ld`) and also passes quite some options to these sub-processes like paths, libraries, multilib information, startup-code, etc. In short: link with

> gcc -o dummy dummy.o

As you only have 1 compilation unit, you can compile, assemble and link with

> gcc -o dummy dummy.c

In order to see the commands that `gcc` is invoking, add option `-v`.

Similar applies for running the assembler.  Having `gcc` run the assembler can simplify the commands, for example when the C preprocessor should run on the asm source (extension `.S` or `.sx`, or use `gcc -x assembler-with-cpp module.asm` for other extensions).