# Inconsistent CPUID results with different callers for some EAX values

Tags: c, assembly, cpuid

```
unsigned int a, b;
a = 0;
b = 0;

for(a=0; a<6; a++)
{
    __asm__("cpuid"
        :"=a"(b)                 /** EAX into b (output) */
        :"0"(a)                  /** a into EAX (input) */
        :"%ebx","%ecx","%edx");  /** clobbered registers */
    printf("a=%d, b=0x%x", a, b);
}
```

Above code prints value of a and b.

In Ubuntu 22, this portion of code I am using for 2 projects. One is quite small one and other is bigger one. I see values of a and b are printed in small and big projects as below.

**a, b values in small project**

```
a=0, b=0x20
a=1, b=0xb06a3
a=2, b=0xfeff01
a=3, b=0x0
a=4, b=0x0
a=5, b=0x40
a=6, b=0xdf8ff7
```

**a, b values in bigger project**

```
a=0, b=0x20
a=1, b=0xb06a3
a=2, b=0xfeff01
a=3, b=0x0
a=4, b=0x7c01c143
a=5, b=0x40
a=6, b=0xdf8ff7
```

You can see in line starting with **a=4**, b value is different for above two cases. I am surprised why values becoming different, ideally values should remain same even if this code is run from different projects.

Can somebody please help me to understand how come values are different.

Comment: ECX is another input to CPUID for some EAX values.  In GNU C, you can just use functions from `cpuid.h` like `__get_cpuid_count` which takes two input args.  (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/i386/cpuid.h / [[Intrinsics for CPUID like informations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17769071))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cpuid

4 is Deterministic Cache Parameters Leaf

Information returned depends on the value in ECX. A 0 result means that ECX did not contain the index of a valid cache.

Try setting ECX to the same value for both and the results should stabilize as well.

Example:

```
__asm__("movl $0,%%ecx;\n\t"
        "cpuid"
    :"=a"(b)                 /** EAX into b (output) */
    :"0"(a)                  /** a into EAX (input) */
    :"%ebx","%ecx","%edx");  /** clobbered registers */
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I set ECX value. This is an existing code, I do not know how to set ECX value. Please give an example.

Comment: @Austin: If you don't understand your inline asm or know how to modify it, replace it with a call to `__get_cpuid_count()` from GCC's `cpuid.h`.  Should compile to the same asm.  (At least for x86-64; in 32-bit code each call to at least some of the wrapper functions first check for availability of CPUID at all, I think.)

Comment: Thanks. If I have to set the ECX value, how to do that, any hint highly appreciated.

Comment: @Austin just added an example with zero. Syntax may be somewhat silly, I'm not all that familiar with inline assembly. More details at https://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Comment: Your example worked fine. Accepting your perfect answer.