# SSE4.1 with gcc, how to have old-compatible code?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, gcc, sse

I have some SSE4.1 spots in my application where I use SSE4.1.

Is there any way to have my application run with SSE4.1 on newer systems and automatically do something like a "fallback" on older systems? I read upon the -mtune option but I'm unable to understand if it does what I need.

Comment: Have you manually written SSE4.1 code, or are you relying on compiler auto-vectorization?

Comment: Manually written. And I don't have fallback code unfortunately :(

Comment: I would be surprised, if GCC emulates inline assembly or intrinsics of newer architectures for the older ones. Assuming you're using intrinsics, one would implement such replacements by hand.

Comment: The compiler may be smart enough to auto-vectorize the same code with multiple instruction sets.  I'm not aware of any that goes backwards, tho.

Comment: uh, so there's no way :( 
I think I will need to either consider writing fallback code or drop support :(

Comment: @Sam: While implementing each intrinsic would be possible, I'd expect that to be a low slower than a version of the code that uses normal arithmetic operations in a loop, just because the level of abstraction difference.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: True. What I meant is, to pick only the ones actually needed. Perhaps, one would be forced to maintain two implementations of an algorithm instead. In my specific case, a replacement for `_mm_popcnt()` was needed. The MIT hakmem was a good candidate to parallelize with older SIMD instrinsics, so I had no losses there.

Comment: You *always* need scalar code to fall back on, not just for backward-compatibility, but also for testing, debugging, measuring performance, portability to other platforms, and to act as working documentation and a reference implementation for anyone who has to work on your code in future.

Comment: @PaulR: That's a "very very strong want", rather than a true need, but yes I agree that an iteration-based version with scalar arithmetic is definitely advantageous for the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No automatic fallback exist.
You should use the __cpuid intrinsic to query for SSE4.1 ISA:
Here how to do it:

```
bool IsSSE41Enabled()
{
   int CPUInfo[4];
    __cpuid(CPUInfo, 1);

    return 0 != (CPUInfo[2] & (1<<19)); // 19th bit of 2nd reg means sse4.1 is enabled
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called "cpu dispatching" the idea is, you have multiple versions of a function, say one SSE capable and one generic, and then you query the cpu during initialization and pick which version you should use (via setting a function pointer or something similar). I'm no expert on the subject but here is a good post on the subject:

[What's the proper way to use different versions of SSE intrinsics in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584983/whats-the-proper-way-to-use-different-versions-of-sse-intrinsics-in-gcc/15610628#15610628)