# GCC Return optimiztion

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'd like to know if GCC can optimize code like

```
int foo(args) {
    if(is_true) {
        do_smth;
        n = call_func(args);
        do_smth;
        return n;
    }
    else {
        return call_func(args);
    }
}
```

so that if i'm in else branch call_func's call would be executed like there was no foo call? I'm writing kernel module, and for solving one particular issue I need it to look like this call_func was called directly. To be more specific call_func is some system call. Foo is my version of this system call. In is_true case I should do smth, call this system call and then return its return. But in !is_true I'd like to somehow change the call stack itself - so that on current level there was call_func instead of foo. Is it even possible?

Implementation of is_true:

```
struct task_struct * cur_task = current;
if(check_dir(cur_task)) {
...
}
```

check_dir is function to check if we want to do something with directory, from which system call was called.

Comment: It depends on how `is_true` is defined/implemented - you might be able to implement some sort of dispatcher, but you'll need to give more details about how you do this test and what it's based on.

Comment: I added implementation. Or it needs even more detailed explanation?

Comment: What about something like a [CPU dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676426/disable-avx2-functions-on-non-haswell-processors/23677889#23677889) as @PaulR mentioned. The first time you set the function pointer to `foo` and after that it points to `call_func`. You can change the function pointer again later to point back to `foo` if you need to.

Comment: @Zboson this isn't a solution for my problem. Problem is in deletion of code after kernel module unloading. Some system calls can still be executing(like blockable read). And after it is executed, it jumps back to my implementation, but there is no code anymore, because process's virtual memory was freed already.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [tail-call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimization (it is *not* specified in any C standard; in contrast, some languages -e.g. Scheme and Ocaml- specify that tail-call optimization is required to happen). In *some* cases, recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compilers can do that [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler).

But it really depends upon the details, in particular of the actual arguments passed to `call_func`

If you depend on it, please comment your code and check with `gcc -fverbose-asm -O2 -S` that your compiler is doing that.

Notice that this optimization is not required, and might be compiler, compilation flags, processor and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific.

<sup>(so it could work on x86-64 but not on 32 bits ia32 or ARM; you really should check!)</sup>

Comment: In fact I'm doing it for several system calls, so arguments depend on particular system call. And stability of system depends on it. If I can optimize like this, I will be able to unload module, and if I can't - I won't.