# C sibling call elimination in call stack

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

My task is to intercept particular system calls, that were called from certain directory.  For each of these system callse I have my implementation, which looks like this

```
int my_syscall(args) {
  struct task_struct * cur_task = current;
  if(check_dir(cur_task)) {
    do_smth;
    n = orig_sys_call(args);
    do_smth;
    return n;
  }
  else {
    return orig_sys_call(args);
  }
}
```

The question is - Is it possible to change somehow `else`section (`return orig_sys_call(args)`), so that after execution of `orig_sys_call(args)` it would return directly to function-caller instead of returning to my implementation?

I want to know can I make this using language instruments, not compiler optimization. I understood from the answer to my earlier question, [GCC Return optimiztion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26775257/1248365), that tail call or sibling call optimization can be done, so now it's different question.

Comment: Didn't you ask [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775257/gcc-return-optimiztion) before ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz gcc optimization and changing code is somehow different, don't u think? It's completely different question