# Create separate object files from the same source code and link to an executable with CMake

Tags: visual-studio, gcc, makefile, cmake

I have two files main.cpp and simd.cpp.  I compile them like this:

```
g++ -c -mavx  -O3 simd.cpp -o simd_avx.o
g++ -c -msse2 -O3 simd.cpp -o simd_sse2.o
g++ -O3 main.cpp simd_avx.o simd_sse2.o
```

Now I want to build this with Cmake.  Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
add_library(avx OBJECT simd.cpp)    
add_library(sse2 OBJECT simd.cpp)

IF(MSVC)    
    set(COMPILE_FLAGS "/openmp /Wall")    
    set_target_properties (avx PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/arch:AVX")   
    set_target_properties (sse2 PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/arch:SSE2 -D__SSE2__")    
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${COMPILE_FLAGS})    
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${COMPILE_FLAGS}")   
ELSE()    
    set(COMPILE_FLAGS "-fopenmp -Wall")    
    set_target_properties (avx PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "-mavx")   
    set_target_properties (sse2 PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "-msse2")    
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${COMPILE_FLAGS})    
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${COMPILE_FLAGS} -O3")   
ENDIF()
add_executable(dispatch main.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:avx> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:sse2>)
```

With MSVC2012 this works fine.  However, it makes two separate folders in the build file, sse and avx, which each point to the same simd.cpp.  I guess this is a fine solution since I can set the properties separately for each folder.  It's a bit annoying having the same source file displayed twice.

But when I make a makefile for GCC in Linux I get the error:

```
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/avx.dir/simd.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/avx.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Can you explain why the Makefile is failing?  Can you suggest a better CMakeLists.txt file to do what I want to do?**

simd.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef __AVX__ 
void func_avx() {
    printf("avx\n");
}
#elif defined ( __SSE2__ )
void func_sse2() {
    printf("sse2\n");
}
#else
// scalar code
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
extern void func_sse2();
extern void func_avx();
       void func_dispatch();
void (*fp)() = &func_dispatch;

void func_dispatch() {
    #ifdef __AVX__
    fp = func_avx;
    #else
    fp = func_sse2;
    #endif
    fp();
}
void func() {
    fp();
}

int main() {
    func();
}
```

Comment: `<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers` something bad happens in command line argument?

Comment: Why are you using `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` for linux and `COMPILE_FLAGS` for msvc?

Comment: Hey! Thanks!  You solved it.  How embarrassing :-/  The COMPILE_FLAGS was defined but not COMPILE_DEFINTIONS.  I changed COMPILE_DEFINTIONS to COMPILE_FLAGS and it works.  I started using cmake yesterday.  Wish I had some warning for this!  I originally intended this post to just be about visual studio and I only tested GCC on linux during the post.  In any case, is this a good soltuion?  If you have a better solution could you post it?

Comment: IS there some way to have Cmake warn me about undefined variables to help avoid these kind of errors in the future?  I just tried using random name and it makes the Makefile with no warning.

Comment: `is this a good soltuion` I think it's quite appropriate for this kind of task. I have some code review thoughts if you want I can make it as an answer)

Comment: `about undefined variables` You add a compile definition, so it's compiler job to report you unused definition warning

Comment: @ruslo, I mean a CMAKE variable defined with set().  I never defined COMPILE_DEFINTIONS but Cmake never warned me.  I can put any random name there and it gives no warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is a misprint:

```
set_target_properties(avx PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "-mavx")
```

Compiler output:

```
> cmake -H. -B_builds -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON
c++ -D-mavx ... 
In file included from <built-in>:
<command line>:1:9: error: macro names must be identifiers
#define -mavx 1
```

So definitions `-mavx` passed to compiler.

#### Notes

- Compiler flags combined from both `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` (for Release build) simultaniously. So there is no need to modify `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` if `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` already modified: [edit #1](http://pastebin.com/744d0jMW)
- `-O3` option already passed to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` no need to modify it (btw you rewrite `-DNDEBUG` release option, I think it's pretty important):
  [edit #2](http://pastebin.com/fhNdY5et)
- Use `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` to modify `-D...` flags (btw you define `__SSE2__` only for msvc, is it correct?): [edit #3](http://pastebin.com/gtJWwcwJ)
- Refactor lit' bit: [edit #4](http://pastebin.com/XCANGNni)
- Now you see one of the popular CMake anti-pattern: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "my flags")`. By default (and sometimes by user needs) `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is **not** empty variable, so right way to modify it is: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} my flags")`:
  [edit #5](http://pastebin.com/qYX7q5k6)
- ... and the question fix: [final](http://pastebin.com/f60qVFYS)

Comment: This is a great answer!  Thank You!  I leaned a lot from it which will save me a lot of time as I'm learning Cmake.