# compiling AVX2 program

Tags: c, gcc, avx, avx2

I have written a program with AVX intrinsics, which works well using Ubuntu 12.4 LTS and GCC 4.6 with the following compilation line: g++ -g -Wall -mavx ProgramName.cc -o ProgramName

The problem started When i have updated the compiler up to 4.7 and 4.8.1 versions to support the 16-bit AVX2 intrinsics, which is not supported in gcc 4.6

Currently, the updated gcc version compiles both AVX and AVX2 programs properly. However, it gives me the following error when i run the program: Illegal instruction (core dumped), although it was working on gcc 4.6

My question is: what is prefect way to compile and run both AVX and AVX2 intrinsics

Comment: I compile the AVX2 program using -mavx2 instead of -mavx

Comment: What was the actual illegal instruction it crashed on?

Comment: Are you sure your processor supports `AVX2`? Presently only Haswell chips do

Comment: You can use CPUID to determine (at run-time) which instruction set extensions are supported by the processor.  This way, your program can decide for itself whether to use AVX or alternate code if AVX is not available.

Comment: @MaratDukhan Broadwell is out too you know

Comment: @harold Indeed, I forget about it

Comment: @harold There is no particular instruction to show error. However, the following instruction does that:
while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, "a:b:m:s:g:e:")) != -1).

Comment: @MaratDukhan I am sure that my processor supports AVX because the program was compiled and ran properly with gcc 4.6 Furthermore, the CPU-Z application shows that my processor supports the following techniques: 
Instructions sets MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, EM64T, VT-x, AES, AVX   
but may you please explain more about how to use the CPUID

Comment: AVX2 is not in that list.

Comment: @harold, Do you mean that i am not able to run AVX2 on my device ??
what do you suggest then ??  please advise.

Comment: There are basically 2 solutions: 1) don't use AVX2, or 2) buy a new computer. As a potential 3rd, have someone else run it, but that makes debugging hard and performance tuning even harder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868235/preventing-gcc-from-automatically-using-avx-and-fma-instructions-when-compiled-w/25911959#25911959

Comment: You can use [Intel's SDE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator/) to test AVX2 code on older CPUs that don't support it.

Answer (score 9):

If you tell gcc to use AVX2, it will do so, regardless of whether your CPU supports them or not. That can be useful for cross-compiling or for examining gcc's code generation, but it's not particularly helpful for running programs. If your program crashes with an illegal instruction exception, it is most likely that your CPU does not support the AVX2 extension.

On i386 and x86-64 platforms (and in certain other circumstances), you can specify the gcc option `-march=native` to generate code for the host machines instruction code. The compiled code might not work on another machine with fewer capabilities, but it should allow you to use all the features of your machine.

While `-march=native` is a good solution for generating executables, it does not actually help much with writing code; you still need to tailor the instrinsics for the target's architecture, and writing code which can take advantage of CPU features without relying on them gets complicated. I don't know of a good C solution, but there are several C++ template frameworks available.

Comment: please note that when i updated the gcc up to 4.8 to support the AVX2, it stopped running AVX and it gives me the error mentioned above. Although, it was running with gcc 4.6.
      Intuitively, the updated compiler should support the techniques supported by the previous versions.  correct ??

Comment: @MROF: It's not guaranteed to work if you compile with `-mavx2` and your CPU doesn't support AVX2. The command-line option does not only control which intrinsics are allowed; it gives the optimizer permission to use AVX2 operations. It's quite possible to gcc 4.8 has more optimizations which use AVX2 opcodes if available.

Comment: The code is working currently on another hardware, and the problem was in the previous device.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to gcc 4.8 likely pulled in AVX512, so you would have needed to limit the generated instr mix to ONLY AVX2 for your machine.

Comment: The OP was using `-mavx2`, not `-mavx512f`.  By default, gcc for x86-64 only targets baseline x86-64, not even assuming cmpxchg16b, SAHF/LAHF, or SSE3.  Only with `-m` options like `-march=skylake-avx512` or `-march=knl`, or `-mavx512f`, will gcc emit AVX512 instructions.