# Compile with AVX2 support and run

Tags: macos, avx

I have a very big library and I want to compile it with AVX2 support (but my processor supports inly AVX). This library also has internal runtime checks whether a processor support AVX2 or not. Something like this:

```
#if __AVX2__
if (support_avx2)
{
    // vectorized code
}
#endif
// simple C++ code
```

I was able to compile the library with AVX2 support, but when I run tests I have got at the very beginning:

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Any ideas? 
The goal is to compile the library with all available optimisations and features and check them in runtime.

p.s. I'm working on OSX

Comment: You code does not check if your processor supports AVX2. It only checks if your compiler options were set for AVX2. What you want is a CPU dispatcher. Here are several links on that [preventing-gcc-from-automatically-using-avx-and-fma-instructions-when-compiled-w](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868235/preventing-gcc-from-automatically-using-avx-and-fma-instructions-when-compiled-w/25911959#25911959).

Comment: Actually, support_avx2 is boolean flag that reflect an appropriate bit of cpuid.

Comment: When you compile for AVX2 your compiler assumes it can use AVX2 whenever it wants (e.g for vectorization). You have to compile for the lowest common denominator (I guess AVX in your case) you want to support for the dispatcher. Then compile separate object files for each AVX and AVX2 and then have the dispatcher jump to the appropriate version.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to run AVX2 code on a CPU that only has AVX (e.g. Sandy Bridge/Ivy Bridge). You could use [Intel's SDE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator/) to run the code for test purposes (this actually works pretty well, for command-line executables at least), but it might just be easier to get a Haswell Mac for development and testing.

Comment: Is Intel's SDE easy to install and use? I have been considering it for AVX512.

Comment: Yes, I found it easy to install (on OS X at least - Linux should be no problem I imagine) and it works well - only the unsupported instructions are emulated and everything else runs at full speed, so it doesn't suffer from the usual problem with CPU emulators where you find yourself running at several orders of magnitude slower than on a real CPU.

Comment: @PaulR, Given a DLL / Dylib / O, is there a way to know which sets of instructions it requires? Thank You.

Comment: @Royi: I guess you could run it through a disassembler and grep the output for specific instructions.

Comment: There is no tool or something like that which automates this?

Comment: @Royi: not that I know of.

Comment: I'd guess there is a demand so I'd expect someone to create this. Thank You. By the way Paul, I'm looking for the fastest SSE / AVX + OpenMP implementation of Image Convolution (Separable + Non Separable). Are you aware of any opensource implementation?

Comment: @Royi: I guess I would start with OpenCV, and if it's not fast enough then look into further optimisations. To get the fastest possible implementation though you usually need to perform specific optimisations with *a priori* knowledge of your kernels and images.

Comment: OpenCV is big... Need something smaller. I don't need it optimized to death but works with any kernel and any image with Separable Mode.

Comment: @PaulR, Fir instance, this is what I did so far: https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/blob/master/ImageConvolution/ImageConvolution/ImageConvolutionGaussianKernel.cpp. Currently only Gaussian Kernel. I wonder if there are Low Hanging Fruits (No Assembly, just something simple to achieve better performance).

Comment: If this is working code then you should probably post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com - there is quite a lot of room for improvement but it's not something that can be dealt with here in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use cpuid to check whether the cpu supports the feature you want to use, then jump to code using it if it does.

The

```
#if __AVX2__
```

relates only to the machine on which you are compiling and is usually set by compiler flags.

Comment: Actually, support_avx2 is boolean flag that reflect an appropriate bit of cpuid

Comment: Well it probably isn't working the way you think it is if you get an illegal instruction as you say. I'd recommend running it under gdb then disassembling so you can see the precise illegal instruction and where it has come from then work backwards from there to locate your bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you only compile for AVX2 your compiler assumes it can use AVX2 when it wants. You have to compile for the lowest common hardware you want to use, then check what hardware is available, and then set your functions to point to appropriate functions from object files compiled with that hardware. This is a [CPU dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868235/preventing-gcc-from-automatically-using-avx-and-fma-instructions-when-compiled-w/25911959#25911959). Here is a lazy man's dispatcher:

```
//foo.cpp
#if __AVX2__
void foo_AVX2() {
    //AVX2 code
    //make sure to call zeroupper!!!
}
#else
void foo_AVX2();
void foo() {
    //simple C++ code
}

int main(void) {
    bool support_avx2 = detect_AVX2();
    if (support_avx2) {
        foo_AVX2();
    }
    else {
        foo();
    }
}
#endif
```

Then compile like this:

```
g++ -c -O3 -mavx2 foo.cpp -o foo_AVX2.o
g++ -O3 foo.cpp foo_AVX2.o
```