# Visual Studio equivalent of GCC's __attribute__((target("sse")))

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

This is the problem I encountered when I tried to migrate an existing GCC project to Visual Studio.

For a given function `void foo()`, I hand-optimize it by sse/avx intrinsics, resulting in two versions of this function `void foo_sse()` and `void foo_avx()`, and I use `cpuid` to invoke the correct version at runtime. To tell GCC that `void foo_sse()` and `void foo_avx()` should be compiled with `-msse` and `-mavx` options respectively, I add `__attribute__((target("sse")))` and `__attribute__((target("avx")))` to their declaration.

It works well for GCC, but I cannot find an equivalent for VS. For some security concerns, I have to put all codes in one single cpp file to mangle symbol names and I cannot simply put two functions in two different cpp files and give them different compiler options.

How can I specify compiler options on a per-function basis in VS? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder if that's even possible. I had to split the function definitions into 2 separate .cpp files in order to apply different compiler flags.

Comment: What about using [one source file but compiling it with different options two create two different object files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790026/compile-with-avx2-support-and-run/27800204#27800204)? MSVC defines `__AVX__` if you use `/arch:AVX` or `/arch:AVX2`.

Comment: If you use `/GL` it will be equivalent to one object file anyway.

Comment: Does not currently exist. Either DIY the functionality, or upvote this issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-function-target-attribute-and-mutiversioning/10130630