How to avoid such terrible codegen (SIMD->memory spilling) on MSVC with branches?
For this code:
#include <immintrin.h>

[[gnu::target("avx2")]]
[[msvc::noinline]]
void f(void *a, bool c, long long &d)
{
        using V = __m256i;
        V v = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<V const *>(a));
        if (c)
        {
                --d;
        }
        V sum = _mm256_add_epi64(
                v,
                _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<V const *>(a)));
        _mm256_storeu_si256(reinterpret_cast<V *>(a), sum);
}

Clang generates:
f(void*, bool, long long&):
        vmovdqu ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdi]
        vmovdqa ymm1, ymm0
        test    esi, esi
        je      .LBB0_2
        dec     qword ptr [rdx]
        vmovdqu ymm1, ymmword ptr [rdi]
.LBB0_2:
        vpaddq  ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
        vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rdi], ymm0
        vzeroupper
        ret

whereas MSVC generates:
void f(void *,bool,__int64 &) PROC                        
$LN5:
        push    rbp
        sub     rsp, 64                            
        lea     rbp, QWORD PTR [rsp+32]
        and     rbp, -32                     
        vmovdqu ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rcx]
        vmovdqu YMMWORD PTR v$1$[rbp], ymm0
        test    dl, dl
        vzeroupper
        je      SHORT $LN2@f
        dec     QWORD PTR [r8]
$LN2@f:
        vmovdqu ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rcx]
        vpaddq  ymm1, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR v$1$[rbp]
        vmovdqu YMMWORD PTR [rcx], ymm1
        vzeroupper
        add     rsp, 64                            
        pop     rbp
        ret     0

Notice that MSVC spills the SIMD register to memory immediately before the branch, then re-loads it right after the branch. Clang, on the other hand, just preserves the variable throughout the branch.
This caught me incredibly off-guard and is a frustrating impediment to optimizing my code.
Is this a known issue? How can I prevent this on MSVC (assuming I need the branch)?

Do you really want  to support long long& d aliasing with void* a?
If not, both would emit better code https://godbolt.org/z/vsr5jv15M

@AlexGuteniev: hm, it didn't occur to me to use __restrict, let me try that when I have a chance and see if it works. My actual code had these as local variables; this is just what I stripped it down to. But the void* isn't the issue here because you get the same issue without that - see e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/YW9Mj98fd

Update: I don't really see a way to apply __restrict to my code. Everything is in local variables without aliasing, but the code is way too complicated for this to solve it.

local pointer variables can also have __restrict, not sure why wouldn't that work

Also, can you avoid the branch by saying d -= c; instead of that if statement?

@AlexGuteniev: My function is like 500 lines of complicated logic with lots of pointer-chasing, not 5 trivial lines and a single pointer being dereferenced. It's WAY too complicated for tricks like these to address the issue. (Yes I tried. Believe me when I tell you these don't cut it.) I need a general solution.

I don't see a generic solution here then, except fixing or changing the compiler. To attempt to fix it, report to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp , it worked for me with a somewhat similar problem. To change, you can use clang toolset with clang-cl compiler that come with Visual Studio. You can use it for some of translation units, rather than all of them, this should work.

@AlexGuteniev: Yep, that's been my guess too. Thanks for the help anyway! The __restrict trick might help someone else down the road.

Is there a reason you don't compile with /arch:AVX2? (I don't know if msvc supports that on a per-function basis): https://godbolt.org/z/srve38Eoz

MSVC appears not to support per-function targets at the moment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714146/visual-studio-equivalent-of-gccs-attribute-targetsse (there is a relatively recent comment under that quite old question).

@chtz: Whoa, it didn't occur to me at all that that might address this issue. I could probably do that here if I split off this function into a separate file and manually dispatch on the CPU features. Thanks for the suggestion - feel free to post that as an answer!
