# C++ AVX2 Instrinsic function Non-Standard Size

Tags: c++, simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I am trying to use AVX2 intrinsic functions with C++. I am using floats `(__m256)`. Now there are 8 floats that can fit in a register. But what happens if I have less than 8 floats, say I have 5. In that case, the lower 3 floats have garbage values.

```
float a[5] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f};
float b[5] = {2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f};

__m256 _a = _mm256_loadu_ps(a);
__m256 _b = _mm256_loadu_ps(b);

__m256 _c = _mm256_div_ps(_a, _b);

for(int i=0; i<8; ++i)
    cout << _c[i] << endl;
```

The result that I get it in the screenshot below:

[image: Result]

Is there any way I can the last 3 numbers in the results to 0? I don't want to run a loop since that would defeat the purpose of using AVX. Also, the number of floats (5 in this case) is variable.

I am new to AVX and would really like some help.

In the context of the larger problem, I read the arrays from a data stream and thus don't know the size of the array beforehand to be able to append 0 at the end of the arrays without running a loop.

Comment: float a[8] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};   You might have to initialise the last 3 members of b to 1.0f

Comment: Don't provide a smaller array to load than the register size.

Comment: Hello James, thanks a lot for the quick response. In the larger context of the problem, the arrays are loaded from a stream and i dont know the size beforehand. So, appending 0 at the end would require a loop from (8-arraysize) which is something i want to avoid. Is there any other solution?

Comment: If your stream is non stop, then you can wait until having 8 floats to fill in your register. That is, treat your stream in blocks of 8.

Comment: Nopes, cant wait till they are 8

Comment: You can use padding (small amount of valid data inside a longer buffer), but you can't safely load from a 5-element array.  It might end right before an unmapped page.  What do you *really* want to do with the result?  Your current code does loop over it.  (Well technically you can use a masked load, `vmaskmovps`, but then you need to convert an integer to a mask.  related: [Vectorizing with unaligned buffers: using VMASKMOVPS: generating a mask from a misalignment count? Or not using that insn at all](//stackoverflow.com/q/34306933))

Comment: Using AVX this way is nonsensical. Using SSE would be nonsensical already for 5 elems at a time, but switching to AVX will give you a warmup which is about 50,000 times as long as it takes with a simple C loop.

Comment: @Damon    I would have expected that AVX just ran a loop in microcode...  Obviously I don't know what I'm talking about...  I would be interested in seeing an answer that says this which explains "warmup"

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: If the current turbo is above the AVX ceiling, running 256-bit vector instructions will limit their throughput to 1 per 4 clocks or something, until after 50k cycles the CPU will downclock and let them run at full throughput.  Or something like that. 
 https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=415 reports seeing it on SKL.  My explanation of the mechanism is a guess based on understanding gained from SKX AVX512 ([SIMD instructions lowering CPU frequency](//stackoverflow.com/q/56852812)) soft transition.  It might be nothing to do with powering down upper 128.

Answer (score 2):

```
float a[5] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f};
float b[5] = {2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f};

__m256 _a = _mm256_loadu_ps(a);
__m256 _b = _mm256_loadu_ps(b);
```

This is undefined behavior because you are reading beyond the array.

You can clear all the elements in `_a` and `_b` with `_mm256_setzero_ps()`:

```
__m256 _a = _mm256_setzero_ps;
__m256 _b = _mm256_setzero_ps;
```

Loading 5 elements into the `__m256` register is a little trickier. If possible, you can declare it with 8 elements. I believe C++ will value initialize with 0.0f.

```
float a[8] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f};
float b[8] = {2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f};
```

If you can't declare the array with 8 elements, then I would probably try something like this with GCC and Clang:

```
__m256 _a = _mm256_setzero_ps(), _b = _mm256_setzero_ps();
memcpy(&_a, a, 5*sizeof(float));
memcpy(&_b, b, 5*sizeof(float));
```

---

You can also copy to an intermediate array and allow the compiler to optimize:

```
float a[5] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f};
float b[5] = {2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f};
float t[0] = {0.0f};

memcpy(t, a, 5*sizeof(float));
__m256 _a = _mm256_loadu_ps(t);
memcpy(t, b, 5*sizeof(float));
__m256 _b = _mm256_loadu_ps(t);
```

(Editor's note: this will likely compile to about the same asm as memcpy into the `__m256` object.  With current compilers, it will actually copy to the stack and result in a store-forwarding stall when reloaded.)

---

A final possibility is loading one full `__m128`, setting the one element in a second `__m128`, and then combining the two `__m128` into a `__m256`. I don't have a lot of experience with it, but this may do what you want. I did not test it:

```
float a[5] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f};
float b[5] = {2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f};

__m256 _a = _mm256_set_m128 (_mm_loadu_ps(a+0), _mm_load_ps1(a+4));
__m256 _b = _mm256_set_m128 (_mm_loadu_ps(b+0), _mm_load_ps1(b+4));
```

The `_mm_load_ps1` will broadcast the the first element (`a[4]` or `b[4]`) into the remaining elements. The remaining elements will *not* be 0, but they won't be random garbage either. When you carry out your calculation, you treat them as *"don't cares"*.

If you truly need the last three elements to be 0.0f, then this should do. But I believe it will cost you two extra instructions as opposed to `_mm_load_ps1`.

```
// x set to {5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}
__m128 x = _mm_insert_ps(_mm_setzero_ps(), _mm_load_ps1(a+4), 0);
```

The full statement for `a` would look like:

```
__m256 _a = _mm256_set_m128 (_mm_loadu_ps(a+0),
    _mm_insert_ps(_mm_setzero_ps(), _mm_load_ps1(a+4), 0));
```

And before you exit your routine that processes the `__m256` datatypes, you may need to call `_mm256_zeroupper`. See questions like [Using AVX CPU instructions: Poor performance without “/arch:AVX”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7839925/608639) and [Using xmm parameter in AVX intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20449379/608639).

Regardless of what you decide, you should benchmark the performance of your application to see which is best for your program.

Also see the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide).

Comment: If you have a compile-time-constant length, it's going to be much better to use `_mm256_maskload_ps` than to get the compiler to make some nasty asm that creates a store-forwarding stall.  That instruction isn't wonderful but it's not terrible either.  Also, your first version with a memcpy directly into `__m256 _a` leaves the high elements uninitialized so it doesn't answer the question.  You could also `vblendps` or `vandps` to clear high bits after a load, if for some other reason you know you can't actually fault.

Comment: Isn't `_mm_insert_ps(_mm_setzero_ps(), _mm_load_ps1(a+4), 0)` just `_mm_load_ss(a+4)`? At least clang seems to generate the same code.

Comment: Yes, you are right Marc. I was looking for that intrinsic but did not find it on my pass through the Intel Intrinsic Guide.