# Enable Enhanced Instruction Set for a single function/file

Tags: visual-studio, sse, cl.exe

Is it possible to enable an enhanced instruction set (SSE/AVX) for a single function or file within a visual studio project? I'd like to have multiple versions of a function which target different instruction sets, all within the same output binary

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to enable custom instruction set for a single **function** or a single **file**. However, you can enable custom instruction set for a single **translation unit**, which is usually a *c*/*cpp* file. Note that the instruction set used in headers depends on how the translation unit is compiled (which includes it) and may be different in different *cpp* files.

I suppose that if you compile different *cpp* files with different instruction sets, you can then link them together, and the resulting binary would work. Actually, it is important to ensure that calling conventions are compatible everywhere, and I think they would be, unless you use something like `__vectorcall` (it requires at least SSE2 BTW).

If you want to compile some functions with multiple instruction sets, you might want to look at the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406658/cpu-dispatcher-for-visual-studio-for-avx-and-sse). In overall it is called "*CPU dispatch*"